# MS Graph API not returning content of One Note page

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access content of a One Note notebook page using graph explorer.
But in response I am getting empty json even if page got some content.
[API used](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bid%7D/onenote/pages/%7Bid%7D/content)

This API is received from list pages response for notes section, so It must be correct.
Not able to understand the problem, Are we only able to capture some specific content from API which doesn't include test content?

Response Header:

```
{
"cache-control": "private",
"client-request-id": "31bbcbba-fb7a-8d07-319f-65a0bb0e3135",
"content-length": "732",
"content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
"etag": "\"{25e13d96-afba-4a0c-9463-64fda7d4fb02}{195}\"",
"preference-applied": "odata.include-annotations=*",
"request-id": "f3ef9c21-2bda-4421-83d5-c2f95768ce72"
```

}

Comment: Have you checked if you have the right permission? Please share the requestid and tinestamp of that request.

Comment: Its a success response, so don't think its a permission issue. ReqId: f3ef9c21-2bda-4421-83d5-c2f95768ce72

Comment: Timestamp as well please.

Comment: Please also try that in POSTMAN.

Comment: Updated response header above, But not able to find timestamp. It will be around18th Jan 2021  2 to 3pm IST.

Comment: I was able to get content from pages, please try to create a page using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-post-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0 and see if it works or not and later try to get content of it. You may see the difference

Comment: I am able to create page using graph Explorer: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/8c30c1e8-8eac-41d6-9c1b-59a6b257e16d/onenote/sections/1-c711458b-ceba-47e6-99e1-05993678485b/pages  {"content":"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>A page with a block of HTML</title></head><body><p>This page contains some <i>formatted</i> <b>text</b>.</p></body></html>"}     which is success and page got created.

Comment: But while getting content still I am getting empty JSON in response. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/8c30c1e8-8eac-41d6-9c1b-59a6b257e16d/onenote/pages/1-933c19df435f469ab0aafaf7680d286d!175-c711458b-ceba-47e6-99e1-05993678485b/content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227529/discussion-between-tod-and-shiva-msft-identity).

Answer (score 0):

Problem not seen when I tried to access same API using .net SDK for graph API.
Seems like issue is with Graph Explorer only which MS team needs to look.
Thanks @Shiva for help.